# Using a smart-relay or a smart-switch to automate smart lights

Tags: smart-lights, home-assistant

I have a couple of smart bulbs in my living area. I have a couple of presence sensors (with lux sensors) in the same room as well. I want to be able to automate the lights so that when someone walks in (and does not switch the lights on), the lights should turn on and when there is no one in the room for X mins, the light turns off.
The automation itself seems ok to setup in my automation platform of choice - home-assistant. But I am not sure which device I should put in place of the switch - a smart switch, or a relay, or something else, since I want the switch should still be workable as a dumb switch for anyone interested in overriding the behaviour. Another requirement is that I should be able to use home-assistant dashboard elsewhere in the house to be able to turn them on / off. So its important that the smart bulb keep getting power, so they don't fall off the network.

Is this something that a Shelly relay can achieve ?

Comment: What kind of network are you using for your devices? WiFi, Zigbee, something else? Do you want to reuse the existing wall switch or is a separate switch OK?

Comment: In the Zigbee world, to convert an existing wall switch into a smart switch you could use one of these https://www.philips-hue.com/fr-fr/p/hue-module-d-interrupteur-mural-philips-hue/8719514318045 not sure if there are equivalents in the Shelly products or other WiFi ranges

Comment: @jcaron - I would like to use either Zigbee or Wifi. The device you have suggested seems like a good option.

Comment: the title of your post does not match the actual question posed about Shelly relay functionality

Answer (score 1):

> But I am not sure which device I should put in place of the switch - a smart switch, or a relay, or something else, since I want the switch should still be workable as a dumb switch for anyone interested in overriding the behaviour.

The answer is "yes". You can use any of these options to control your bulbs.

- I've got several places where I've added Shelly 1 devices (a relay) behind a standard dumb toggle switch to control dumb (but dimmable) LED bulbs. I put the Shelly in "Edge" mode, so it acts as a 3-way switch (in the US, 2-way rest of the world), meaning that the lights can be toggled on/off either physically at the switch or digitally via the Shelly.
- I've recently discovered [Inovelli](https://inovelli.com/) and have become a fan of their switches (satisfied user, no commercial interest in the company). They support both ZigBee (their Blue line) and Z-Wave (their Red line). These work very well with smart bulbs - you can set the Smart Bulb Mode from within HA, and a press of the off-paddle on the switch will send a signal to the bulbs to turn themselves off, but will still leave power flowing to the bulb so it stays on the network. The up/down paddles can respond to up to 5 presses each (yes, a penta-tap) so there are all *kinds* of programming/scene options. They also work as a dimmer (press-hold) if you have dimmable bulbs.

I'm sure there are dozens of other options, these are just the two I'm familiar with. Really, it comes down to

1. What protocol(s) are you currently running
2. How much you're willing to spend
3. What you really want to do

Answer (score 0):

Since Home Assistant uses Z-wave, I would suggest Fibaro devices.  I am using the Fibaro Home Center as well.  The Fibaro [Switch](https://www.fibaro.com/en/products/switches/) or Fibaro [Dimmer](https://www.fibaro.com/en/products/dimmer-2/) can be used.  You mount them behind the wall switch.  The wall switch works as normal.

It can be disconcerting that every time the switch toggles, the state changes.  And the switch in the down position can mean on or off.  For this reason, I am using momentary switches.  They are spring loaded, so they make contact and return to their original position.  Every press changes the state.

Switch Wiring

[image]

Dimmer Wiring

[image]

Comment: Home Assistant uses whatever protocol you install an integration for. I've been running HA for 2 years and have precisely _zero_ Z-wave devices. Mine are all ZigBee and WiFi. A couple of your answers here almost seem like you're advertising for Fibaro...

Comment: @FreeMan, i am not associated with Fibaro. In fact we have had a rough history. But its what I use and what I know best.